# what are the APIs used by various programming languages to develop Web Services based on WS-I organization standards

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, programming-languages, uddi

For developing our application to communicate on network irrespective of platform or language we are using Web Services technology. The standards to develop these applications is given by WS-I (Web Services Interoperability Organization).

So, what languages provided what API's to develop these Applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my Knowledge, for **JAVA**

*Network Communication(HTTP)* - Servlet/EJB API
*XML* - JAXP (Java API for XML Processing), JAXB (Java Architecture for XML Binding)
*UDDI* - JAXR (Java API for XML Registries)
*SOAP* - SAAJ (SOAP with Attachments API for Java)
*WSDL* - WSDL4j

WS-I released two versions.

1. BP 1.0
2. BP 1.1

Java released JAX-RPC API for BP 1.0, JAX-WS API for BP 1.1

**NOTE**: Correct me, if I am wrong